# A pattern to match until "::" not working with string.gsub

Tags: string, lua, gsub, lua-patterns

I'm trying to match any if statement ending with ::, and replace it with 'if (condition) then'.

For example:

```
if (x) ::
```

should be replaced with

```
if (x) then
```

I'm using `string.gsub` to achieve this, but it seems that my pattern isn't correct.  The following code only matches one if statement, but I want it to match all of them.

```
local code = [[

    if (x) ::

    end

    if (y) ::

    end

]]

print(code:gsub("(if.+)::", "%1 then"))

--[[
  what I wanted:

  if (x) then

  end

  if (y) then

  end



  what I got:

  if (x) ::

  end

  if (y) then

  end
]]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `code:gsub("(if.-)::", "%1 then")`; note the use of `-` instead of `+` as it makes the repetition "non-greedy" and it will capture the smallest number of "any character". `.+` in the original pattern matches everything to the end of the line and then backtracks until it finds `::`, but it only finds the last one; that's why you only get one replacement.

Using `(if.-)::` generates the output you expect:

```
if (x)  then

end

if (y)  then

end
```

Comment: I was hoping for the output to say

`if (x) then 

end`

`if (y) then 

end`

(basically replacing any :: with 'then'.)  However, I need to match the whole if statement, not just the ::

Comment: Right; I mistyped the pattern; should use `-`.